# Transferring contact form inquiries to an email account without an email server or an email forwarding service

Tags: email, mediawiki

I have a WordPress/Drupal/MediaWiki website with some all-default contact form.

I desire to transfer contact form inquiries to my email account (Gmail) without using an email server or an email forwarding service.

Is this even possible?
Maybe by using my own email account as **forwarding-to-itself** somehow?

Comment: As I said in your other question, you just configure your contact form to send to that email address.  I'm not sure why you think this would ever require an email server or a forwarding service.

Comment: Hi @StephenOstermiller I was sure it would because in the past, after Installing WordPress with CF7 on a personal DigitalOcean VPS I couldn't transfer contact form inquiries this way at all unless I installed an email server OR configuring email forwarding service (Gmail-1 (Gmail proxy) --- to Gmail 2 (my personal Gmail)).

Comment: What were you using as the "To" and "From" address?   Have you configured `sendmail` to [send email to Google's servers like this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167043/how-do-i-configure-exim4-to-send-mail-through-a-password-protected-ssl-smtp-mail)  Note that `sendmail` is an email client not an email server.  It doesn't run all the time, it is the standard Linux email sending client that can be configured to use Google's SMTP servers.

Comment: I never worked with `sendmail` before (not knowingly at least). I think I misunderstand what is to "To" and "From" here.